# How to deploy multiple services to AWS ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I have a docker-compose setup made up with 2+ containers that I use for local development. I'm trying to deploy the following to AWS ECS and I successfully deployed the first service but I'm struggling deploying more. It seems like I'm missing something in the configuration.

To deploy the first service to ECS, I followed these steps:

1. Deployed docker image to ECR
2. Created an ECS cluster
3. Created a task that I attached my ECR image to
4. Configured a VPC
5. Configured ELB
6. Successfully launched a new instance inside of my ECS container

To deploy the second service, I'm trying to follow steps 1,3 and 6 and it seems like it's deployed successfully. However, when I try to hit any endpoint from the second service, it results in /404 at the first one.

As I understand, my current ELB configuration is set up to route all the traffic to the first instance, so my question is - which steps I should also re-use while deploying the 2nd service? Should it have a separate ELB and security group?

I tried googling it but all the articles are about deploying a single instance which I had no problems with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to create a cluster for second service. You need create another task definition with new image of second service (deployed to the ECR). Next step is create a service in the cluster and setup *Service discovery* in the *Configure network* step.

[`Documentation`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/Welcome.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider this:  https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/ecs-integration/.  It's still in beta but it can deploy your compose file directly to ECS for you.

Comment: I have deployed my project with this approach and I can say it is way more simple than the ECS CLI way, but as of now it supports only fargate and in documentation also they haven't mentioned anything about EC2.